# angular variable to php

Tags: php, jquery, angularjs, ajax

i can't make it works. Could somebody help me?
I would like to show user detail information after click on link, but i don't know how to send information to php file with a link.

i have link to detailed user information like:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:searchText | orderBy:'finish_date'">
          <td><a href="#/user/{{user.user_id}}">{{user.name + ' ' + user.lastname}}</a></td>
          <td> {{user.begin_date}}</td>
          <td> {{user.finish_date}}</td>
</tr>
```

and controller:

```
gymiControllers.controller('UserDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',  function ($scope, $http) {
      console.log($scope.user.user_id);
      $http.get('php/UserDetailsGetData.php?user_id=user.user_id"').success(function(data) {
        $scope.user = data;
      });
    }]);
```

and php file, which should get variable from angular ;-):

```
$user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
```

Comment: you're passing the string "user.user_id" as the user_id parameter

Comment: console.log in UserDetailCtrl Controller say it: TypeError: Cannot read property 'user_id' of undefined.
How to retrieve it from this angular thing :)

Answer (score 2):

Correct it to:

```
gymiControllers.controller('UserDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',  function ($scope, $http) {
      console.log($scope.user.user_id);
      $http.get('php/UserDetailsGetData.php?user_id='+$scope.user.user_id).success(function(data) {
        $scope.user = data;
      });
    }]);
```

Comment: seems does not work:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'user_id' of undefined

Comment: is 'UserDetailCtrl' the controller of your ng-repeat?

Comment: ng-repeat with link is contained in "ActiveListCtrl" controller and after click ngRoute  directs to another view with controller "UserDetailCtrl"

Comment: that's why the $scope is empty. I suggest you to save the User information in a Factory or Angular Service and then inject it in UserDetailsCtrl, alternatively you could use a localstorage or $rootscope but it would be a bad choice.